# Can we use Translation Manager when we have multiple languages in a single publication?

Tags: blueprint, translation-manager

We are setting up a small site with multiple languages, for example, mycompany.com/en/en, mycomany.com/fr/fr, etc. It is very convenient to setup one publication for this, since there aren't that many pages.

However, I can't make use of Tridion Translation Manager if I set it up as one publication (can I?). Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: When you say Tridion Translation System, do you mean Translation Manager? I'll retag your question for that, but let me know if I understood wrong.

Comment: Yes, I mean Translation Manager

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tridion Translation Manager requires separate publications. I expect your initial convenience of only having to set up one publication would not turn out very convenient after a short while, but you can of course always copy-paste translations around. :)

Comment: I tried to setup separate publications, but I run into issues as well. The problem is that we are going to use a single domain to server all languages, for example, mycompany.com/us/en, mycompany.com/de/de, etc. I have setup  a publication for each language, so US English will published to the /us/en folder, and Germany publishes to /de/de. However, the root of the IIS website is /, and the root of each publication is /us/en, etc. Those two are not in sync. I have not found a way to achieve this. Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to ask this as a separate question. It's not translation manager specific and you might be limiting the audience for the question by having it as a comment to a TM specific question.

Answer (score 6):

The Blueprint facilitates localization and translation in Tridion.  You certainly can dump all your pages into one publication, but, as Lars mentions, this setup will bite you hard not too far down the road.

It seems that what you are looking for is a way to manage your website pages in one publication.  A common practice is to setup a main (master) publication to manage your website regardless of language (e.g. In your company's default language), and have child language publications inheriting the site structure and pages.  You would also keep the content in separate Content language publications higher up the Blueprint.  This enables working and localizing content separately, while keeping your site structure and pages the same across languages. So in essence, manage local content, but one (main) website.

Here is an illustration:
http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/classic-blueprint.png

There is even a feature in the publishing dialog allowing to publish child pages down the Blueprint, so that you don't have to navigate across publications to publish - simply do it all from the master website pub.

Comment: Thanks, Nickoli. We are pretty much follow the exact diagram as you show in our main website. This is a small microsite with small number of pages (maybe 30 pages), so it seems a lot of work for such a small number of pages. I am looking for something simpler but can still make use of translation service (without copy and paste around translations)